# spoj prime conjecture PRIMEZUK

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

I am trying to solve the question     http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIMEZUK/

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
#include<math.h>
#define l long long
 using namespace std;
l chk(l a)
{
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(a);++i)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            return a/i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
main()
{
//  freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    int t,n,a;
    l prod=1,flag;
    //t=inp();
    cin>>t;
    for(int j=1;j<=t;++j)
    {
        cin>>n;
        //n=inp();
        if(n==0)
        prod=-1;
        else
        prod=1;
        while(n--)
        {
            cin>>a;
            //a=inp();
            prod*=a;
        }
        ++prod;
        flag=chk(prod);
        if(!flag)
        printf("Case #%d: %lld\n",j,prod);
        else
        printf("Case #%d: %lld\n",j,flag);
    }
}
```

i am getting right answer for the sample test case but whne i submit i am getting wrong answer...any hints???

Comment: there is one more website of stackexchange [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...best suited places for such questions

Comment: #define l long long - that is a criminal offence against programming

Answer (score 2):

You are getting wrong answer because "return a/i" may also return a non-prime number.So you should check whether "return a/i" is prime or not..

Try This...

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

long long int check(long long int a)//Function to check whether a number is prime or not
{
    long long int i,k;
    k=sqrt(a);
    for(i=2;i<=k;++i)
    {
        if(a%i==0) // if not prime
            return check(a/i); //then find greatest prime
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int j=1,t;
    long long int n,a,prod,flag;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        if(n==0)
            prod=-1;
        else 
            prod=1;
        while(n--)
        {
            scanf("%lld",&a);
            prod*=a;
        }
        ++prod;
        printf("Case #%d: %lld\n",j,check(prod));
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, welcome to SO. You should fix code formatting a little bit. Also please remove all redundant information - your signature at the beginning and end. Instead please update your profile information. Also avoid using all capital letters. We don't need to shout at each other :) We should keep answers as clean and straight to the point as possible. Thanks.

Comment: If you do all the above, I will vote your answer up. I've checked on spoj and your code passes and is accepted.

Comment: Yes I agree. But for answer to be as much useful and easy to understand as possible it should be concise and only contain required information. Every first user post is reviewed and I'm just doing that. Just  wanted to improve your answer and introduce you to some tips for good answers. Once again welcome to SO :)